Cloud config server with profile files and spring boot app
I have bound my application to config server. It is able to pull properties from cloud.yml files but it is not using properties from env specific yml files like {my-app}-{profile(dev/test)}.yml.
When the application is deployed to a specific env, it should use properties from both cloud and test specific files.
manifest.yml
applications:
- name: abc
  services:
    - config-server-dev
    - SERVICE_REGISTRY
  env:
    SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: cloud, dev

Location of configurations to activate
We have git repository for config files. We have for example cloud.yml and {my-app}-{profile(dev/test)}.yml ... files.  Common properties are defined in cloud.yml and env specific in {my-app}-dev.yml/{my-app}-test.yml/{my-app}-prod.yml...   We get the property parmas in the java files from these files.
@Value("${product.url}")
private String myproduct;

The problem is that the application is able to pull cloud.yml files but not env specific files.
Where the profiles are specified
PCF:      in pcf we have option in settings to configure 'Spring Cloud Config Server' like below:
      {
      "git" : {
                ......
               "baseDir" : "xxx",
        "privateKey" : "xxx",
        "sourceUri" : "git hub url for config repo",
        "periodic" : true,
        "ignoreLocalSshSettings" : true,
        "defaultLabel" : "git hub branch name of config repo ",
        "sourcePrivateKey" : "xxx",
        "label" : "git hub branch name of config repo",
        "uri" : "xxxxxx"
      }
         ------
         -------      
    }

PCF configuration will be bounding the git repo and spring cloud config server.
Application side: In the application, the manifest.yml file mentions spring active profile as cloud and dev
Logs:
Application.logStartupProfileInfo- The following 2 profiles are active: "cloud", "dev"
ConfigServerConfigDataLoader.log- Fetching config from server at : https://config-server-xxx-xxxtest.net
ConfigServerConfigDataLoader.logTo- Located environment: name=application, profiles=\[cloud,dev\], label=null, version=null, state=null
ConfigServerConfigDataLoader.logTo- Fetching config from server at : https://config-server-xxx-xxxtest.net
ConfigServerConfigDataLoader.logTo- Located environment: name=application, profiles=\[default\], label=null, version=null, state=null```

